# Angular 6 Passing injectables array to providers in app.module.ts causes: "Error in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, angular6

I have the following array with **injectables** that are connected from **services**:

```
import { YouTubeSearchService,
     YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
     YOUTUBE_API_URL } from './you-tube.service';

export const youTubeSearchInjectables: Array<any> = [
    { provide: YouTubeSearchService, useClass: YouTubeSearchService },
    { provide: YOUTUBE_API_KEY, useClass: YOUTUBE_API_KEY },
    { provide: YOUTUBE_API_URL, useClass: YOUTUBE_API_URL }
];
```

And I am trying to pass it to providers in **app.module.ts**:

```
/*other imports*/
import { youTubeSearchInjectables } from './search-result/you-tube-search.injectables';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SimpleHttpComponent,
    SearchResultComponent,
    SearchBoxComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [youTubeSearchInjectables],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

However, I get **"ERROR in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"** (Just one line, nothing else).

I believe the reason has, most probably, something to do with version of Angular. I am using 6 and the book project is written in version 5. However, Angular documentation on Dependency Injection says that the book-way is the right way... So I am a bit confused. Or maybe I am simply missing something.

I actually tried manually adding each injectable into app.module, but got the same error.

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**: tried *"providedIn: 'root',"*
in accordance with ng6 update, but that didn't help.

Just in  case - the injectable class:

```
/*imports*/

export const YOUTUBE_API_KEY = 'keykeykey';
export const YOUTUBE_API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class YouTubeSearchService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(YOUTUBE_API_KEY) private apiKey: string,
    @Inject(YOUTUBE_API_URL) private apiUrl: string
  ) { }

  search(query: string): Observable<SearchResult[]> {
    // logic
  }
}
```

Comment: Do all of the Components in your module declarations array actually exist and are you importing them? I was able to get the same error by copying all of your code into a new Angular project, and the error goes away if I remove SimpleHttpComponent, SearchResultComponent, SearchBoxComponent from the array.

Comment: @JimPerris, all mentioned components exist. I tried to remove them from declarations array as you did. But error is still there

Comment: Does using `useValue` instead of `useClass` with `YOUTUBE_API_URL` and `YOUTUBE_API_KEY` help at all?

Comment: @MattStrom Just found that exactly that was a problem. I changed useClass to useValue in API and URL and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

I see two problems with your code. The first is that you are using an array inside of an array to define your providers. Either reference the `youTubeSearchInjectables` variable straight or use the spread operator to concatenate your exported providers into the providers array of the module.

The second issue, which you will not notice until the first issue is solved, is that you should use `useValue` instead of `useClass` for `YOUTUBE_API_KEY` and `YOUTUBE_API_URL` since these two are not classes but simple string values.

```
const youTubeSearchInjectables: Array<any> = [
  { provide: YouTubeSearchService, useClass: YouTubeSearchService },
  { provide: YOUTUBE_API_KEY, useValue: YOUTUBE_API_KEY },
  { provide: YOUTUBE_API_URL, useValue: YOUTUBE_API_URL }
];

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    ...youTubeSearchInjectables
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```